# How do I make my program execute properly?

Tags: c#

This is my code and everytime I execute my program it starts up normally and crashes. How do I solve this problem to make it function properly?

After debugging I get the following: rnd Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.    System.Random

playnumber  Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away. int

play Cannot obtain value of the local variable or argument because it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.    bool

```
Random rnd = new Random(); 
int playnumber = rnd.Next();

bool play = true; 

while (!play)
{
    Console.Write("\n\Guess a number between 1 and 20: ");
    int number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (number < playnumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tThe given number " + number + " is to low, try again!.");
    }

    if (number > playnumber)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tThe given number " + number +  " is to high, try again!.");
    }

    if (number == playnumber)
        Console.WriteLine("\tCongrats, you guessed right!");
        play = false;
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "it crashes"? Do you get an exception? If so, what is the exception message and stack trace? Have you debugged your program to identify *where* it crashes?

Comment: You should give more information about, what you expect and what happens. Then we might help why it didn't work

Comment: Let me make a guess: It isn't a crash, it's just that it doesn't do anything since `bool spela` is `true` and the while check for it to be `false`, the program just ends.

Comment: This piece of code has multiple flaws. It might not even compile, because it is missing a bracket at the end. Also, be aware of that last if-statement. `spela=false` will always be called, since you are missing `{}`.

Comment: Sorry it's hard to understand a code with variables named like "spela"

Comment: Beyond a crash there are numerous issues with your code, can you clarify whether this is your actual code or just a facsimile? Here are some examples: `slumpat.Next()` will not return a  number in the range 1-20. `spela=true` will make your `while`-loop not run at all. `\Gissa` in the Console.Write won't even compile because `\G` is not a legal character.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the code provided; you have **2** issues:

```
Random slumpat = new Random(); 
int speltal = slumpat.Next();

bool spela = true; 

//DONE: while (spela) - we loop while spela == true
// In your current implementation while never runs
while (spela)
{
    Console.Write("\n\Gissa på ett tal mellan 1 och 20: ");
    int tal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (tal < speltal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tDet inmatade talet " + tal + " är för litet, försök igen.");
    }

    if (tal > speltal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tDet inmatade talet " + tal +  " är för stort, försök igen.");
    }

    if (tal == speltal)
    {   //DONE: braces - you wnat to show the message AND change spela to false 

        Console.WriteLine("\tGrattis, du gissade rätt!");
        spela = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that it crashes my answer is just a guess: it is **not** a crash.

```
bool play = true;
```

this variable is always `true` so the while:

```
while (!play)
```

won't do anything since it's the same as:

```
while (play == false)
```

which is clearly never met. The program just ends.

### Solution

Change the while to `while(play)`.

Also this

```
if (number == playnumber)
        Console.WriteLine("\tCongrats, you guessed right!");
        play = false;
```

should be with brackets

```
if (number == playnumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\tCongrats, you guessed right!");
    play = false;
}
```

Comment: While your solution would work - it makes the code far less readable - by quickly reading the code you would expect to be playing the game when the field/variable called "play" is true not false.

Comment: Fixed, the variable was called "spela" before so it was difficult to say what it meant.